# Fetch contacts/friends email address in Google SignIn in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, gmail, google-signin

I am trying to integrate the Google SignIn with my iOS app.
I followed the tutorial given by Google on:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/
I have been able to get the user log in into the app using the Google SIgnIn.
I am able to retrieve the basic information of the user like name, email address.
I am unable to get the list of friends/contacts and their email address. 
Is there any way I can achieve the same?

Thanks in advance.